# Django slow loading page due to lots of codes

Tags: python, django, django-views, nlp

I am implememting a small recommendation feature on my home page which will suggest jobs to candidates. To accomplish the latter, I have used CountVectorizer and Cosine Similarity. However, to perform this, I had to concatenate lots of fields from the candidate's profile and job description.

This code is defined in the views.py. Every time I load the home page, this view gets executed and eventually, it takes time to load.

Is there something I can do to improve the loading speed? Thank you guys ;)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mre]...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, to make it short, in my views.py, I have a function def home(request) for displaying the homepage. However, this view contains all the logic for finding recommendations for candidates. This is why every time, I go on the home, the logic gets executed and the page takes a lot of time to load :/